# Use ajax value for setting value for select in form

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax in a form and it works excellent. I dont understad how I can get that value in a select form?

```
$(document).on('click','.update',function(e) {
    var id=$(this).attr("data-id");
    var vem=$(this).attr("data-vem");
    $('#id_u').val(id);
    $('#vem_u').val(vem);
});
```

This works fine, I get the requested value:

```
<label>VEM</label>
<input type="text" id="vem_u" name="vem" class="form-control">
```

My problem is to get selected value, php dont work

```
<label>VEM</label>
<select name="vem" id="vem_u" class="form-control">
<option value="0"<?php if ($row["vem"] == 0) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Choose</option>
<option value="1"<?php if ($row["vem"] == 1) { echo " selected"; } ?>>Vem</option>
</select>
```

Can someone please help me?

I'm using this script:
https://softwarepush.net/php-crud-application-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Where is your AJAX code?

Comment: What does the HTML that "works fine" have to do with the JS code? It doesn't have `class="update"`, and there's no `data-id` or `data-vem`.

Comment: Are you updating the form with data retrieved from the server using ajax? Or are you using ajax to send data from the form to the server?

Comment: The above code is getting value from database before sending data.
I'm using the scipt at https://softwarepush.net/php-crud-application-using-jquery-ajax/

So when I want to update the form works fine. But I want the retrieved value to get marked as selected in a select-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you click the update (class) element, you want to pass the selected value of the select box using ajax as parameter "vem" to a url

```
$(document).on('click','.update',function(e) {

var e = document.getElementById("vem_u");
var value = e.value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "vem": value} 

        success: function(response) {
            result = response;
        }
    });

    return result; 

});
```

Comment: When i click a post for editing it, I want the given value in <input type="text" id="vem_u" name="vem" class="form-control"> to get marked as selected in a select-tag. Then send data to server.